# Drupal site performance

Tags: drupal, caching

I have used Drupal 6 for my multilingual website. I am getting issue of site performance I have enabled the cache setting of drupal but it still going slow when move from one page to other.
I have also used boost module but it’s not comfortable for multilingual website.

Please tell me any other way so I will improve performance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of hardware are you running it on? Dedicated or shared? How many concurrent users? There is so much information missing here

Comment: What load levels? Plugins? Any customised code? Database on local server or another server? etc.

Answer (score 0):

your question has a whole host of answers, instead of listing all (which i would have to copy from several sites), here are a few main ones, and some resources i'd recommend:

-> Turn off all modules you are not using

-> Turn on caching

-> Try using the memcache module

-> Enable drupal JS and CSS aggregation, so we would have less files to load, meaning less HTTP requests

-> Use a CDN

-> GZIP contents

-> Minify Javascript

-> Avoid Redirects

-> Reduce Duplicate Scripts

---

Some Resources I would Recommend

http://wimleers.com/article/improving-drupals-page-loading-performance

http://drupal.org/node/326504

http://groups.drupal.org/node/85979

http://groups.drupal.org/node/195218

http://www.bootstrappingindependence.com/technology/how-to-improve-website-performance-with-drupal-php-mysql-and-apache/

http://www.vmirgorod.name/blog/tuning-drupal-performance

http://pronovix.com/blog/my-favorite-drupal-performance-hacks

http://fenix-solutions.com/blog/2009/12/09/tips-for-improving-drupal-performance/

http://drupalst.com/blog/improving-drupal-performance

Comment: Hi

Thanks for your all reply...

I am using amazon EC2 server with following configuration.

1) 100GB EBS volume 
2) 4GB and Dual Core

It's still giving slow performance.

Also, is there any other option than caching data to improve performance of site because caching will note reflect the changes immediately on site.

I Need to confirm that is the performance of Drupal site is depend on the size of database? Please let me know this.

Please give me the exact way so i will solve this issue ASAP.

Thanks very much :)

Comment: no the performance of drupal is not affected much by size of database. But if you have lots of modules installed, this can cause some serious performance issues. I would advise installing the devel module and check all the queries at page load. See which queries are taking lots of time

Comment: Hi 

Thanks again, i have installed the devel module and debug the number of queries which are loaded on each request.
Is there any module to avoid this query execute again and again? Also, Tell me if there any othere way becasue my site contain subdomains
like in.XXX.com,sg.XXX.com so caching is risky... for this because it will not redirect i have tested this.

Thanks

Comment: i dont think there is a module to avoid redundant queries, what you can do is check where the queries are being called from and try to debug from there. I'd appreciate you selecting this as the answer if it answers ur que. Regards

Answer (score 0):

The same issue I have faced in one of my application, I have worked on the following steps and it increases the performance which I verified through YSlow and GooglePageSpeed.

1. If you are using Apache, Replace Apache with NGINX as the web server for your Drupal site. This improves performance and reduces memory utilization when thousands of connections run concurrently. (Apache allocates memory to every additional connection, so it tends to start swapping to disk as concurrent connections increase)
2. Implementation of reverse proxy server. NGINX is a very popular reverse proxy server for Drupal sites. Implementing a reverse proxy server removes the burden of handling Internet traffic from your application server and allows other performance‑enhancing steps: caching of static files and the use of multiple load‑balanced application servers.
3. Implementation of CDN (Content Distribution Network)
4. Implementation of browser level caching at server level
5. Should enable Compression of images, CSS and Javascript files.
6. You can use Akamai for node/page level caching as a result it will increase the performance.
7. Use image sprites (css3embed), avoid iframes if you are using
8. Index database tables (use dbtuner)
9. Use of adding an Expires header
10. Disable DbLog module if not in use.
11. Move your assets at bottom
12. Reduce DNS lookups
    Hope it would help. 
    Thanks

Answer (score -1):

you need realy fast hosting, i recommend use nginx with phpfpm. without any var or opcode cacher your perfomance will be just incredible. im my vps i have speed up big drupal site to 200ms per page

and of course you must to audit your site for slow queries (big views, many blocks or php code).

Comment: Hi

Thanks for your all reply...

I am using amazon EC2 server with following configuration.

1) 100GB EBS volume 
2) 4GB and Dual Core

It's still giving slow performance.

Also, is there any other option than caching data to improve performance of site because caching will note reflect the changes immediately on site.

I Need to confirm that is the performance of Drupal site is depend on the size of database? Please let me know this.

Please give me the exact way so i will solve this issue ASAP.

Thanks very much :)